# VB.net How to make a picturebox non useable

Tags: vb.net

I have been making this game in VB 2010 express and it is my first game ever. And i'm using pictureboxes as my character house lake chests and such. And i've been having a few issues with it. One of them is that i made it like when my character (Picturebox1/myplayer) touch the chest (Picturebox2) it will give me the option to either open the chest og leave it. And if your choice is to open the chest the you get 10 coins. But when i have opened the chest and got the 10 coins i can't get it to be non useable so i can do it infinity times and still get coins.

```
Private Sub mymap_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Dim Loc As Point
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.W
            If Not myplayer.Location.Y - 5 < 0 Then
                Loc = New Point(myplayer.Location.X, myplayer.Location.Y - 5)
                myplayer.Location = Loc
            End If

        Case Keys.S
            If Not myplayer.Location.Y + 5 < 0 Then
                Loc = New Point(myplayer.Location.X, myplayer.Location.Y + 5)
                myplayer.Location = Loc
            End If

        Case Keys.A
            If Not myplayer.Location.X - 5 < 0 Then
                Loc = New Point(myplayer.Location.X - 5, myplayer.Location.Y)
                myplayer.Location = Loc
            End If
        Case Keys.D
            If Not myplayer.Location.X + 5 < 0 Then
                Loc = New Point(myplayer.Location.X + 5, myplayer.Location.Y)
                myplayer.Location = Loc
            End If
    End Select
   If myplayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox2.Bounds) Then
        Chest1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

And then it opens the option between opening the chest or not.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    MsgBox("You found 10 coins in the chest")
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    HouseBuy.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    HouseSell.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Can any1 help me?

Comment: `picturebox2.enabled = false` or `button1.enabled=fale` not sure if you want to disable the picturebox or button that gives the coins

Comment: That, or just set a flag or status indicating that the action occurred, and check it on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "game state".  You'd need to store somewhere, somehow the information that the chest has already been used.  In a robust game you could use Classes to represent the elements in the game.  This would allow you to store many attributes about each item, which could be queried and updated by the user interface.

A simple solution, however, would be to store something in the Tag() property of PictureBox2.  If there is nothing in the Tag() property then display Chest1:

```
    If myplayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox2.Bounds) Then
        If IsNothing(PictureBox2.Tag) Then
            Chest1.Show()
        End If
    End If
```

Be sure to put something in the Tag() property afterwards to prevent it from being opened again:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    MsgBox("You found 10 coins in the chest")
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    Form1.PictureBox2.Tag = True ' <-- disable the Chest
    HouseBuy.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    HouseSell.ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
End Sub
```